# PHP script copy file from webserver to standalone mac osx

Tags: php, macos, ssh

I am trying to connect to a mac osx.
But i am getting errors.
How in the world can i copy files to this mac?

Also i have the following:

afp://192.xxx.x.x

smb://192.xxx.x.x

name@192.xxx.x.x

**ERRORS:**

> Warning: ssh2_connect(): Unable to connect to 192.xxx.x.x on port 22
>   in /home/test.php on line 7
>
> Warning: ssh2_connect(): Unable to connect to 192.xxx.x.x in
>   /home/test.php on line 7 fail: unable to establish connection

**PHP Script:**

```
if (!function_exists("ssh2_connect")) die("function ssh2_connect doesn't exist");
// log in at server1.example.com on port 22

if(!($con = ssh2_connect("192.xxx.xx.xx", 22))){
echo "fail: unable to establish connection\n";
} else {
// try to authenticate with username root, password secretpassword
if(!ssh2_auth_password($con, "", "")) {
    echo "fail: unable to authenticate\n";
} else {
    // allright, we're in!
    echo "okay: logged in...\n";

    // execute a command
    if (!($stream = ssh2_exec($con, "ls -al" ))) {
    echo 123;
    echo "fail: unable to execute command\n";
    } else {

    // collect returning data from command
    stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
    $data = "";
    while ($buf = fread($stream,4096)) {
        $data .= $buf;
    }
    ssh2_exec($con, 'ls -al; echo "__COMMAND_FINISHED__"' );
    fclose($stream);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: looks like port 22 is not open for inbound connections on the machine you are trying to connect to.

Comment: @MarkChorley, how can i enable this on a mac?

Comment: Or you don't have ssh daemon running. Google it? It's not really a programming question and might be specific to your OS version

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwjPsaqunprKAhVDwI4KHSwUAXUQFggjMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F24972534%2Fphp-ssh2-ssh2-connect&usg=AFQjCNHDCRP13xuqEPQuG6R4RUzruXHIuA&sig2=wYoZj5NKdAITKLUu13GhCQ&cad=rja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We open the port 22 to the wright.